# Sql Server Database Mail To Send RDL Report

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services, sql-server-2014, sql-agent-job

Using Sql Server in my last job we had a stored procedure that passed the a reporting services report address and parameters and sent the report as pdf to an email address via database mail.

I've looked everywhere for instructions on how i can achieve this as i would like to set up an agent job that runs on a Thursday night that runs through a list of invoice numbers and email addresses and sends these reports via email to the address on the same row

Answer (score 0):

The procedure you've been using is probably not part of sql server. AFAIK there is no such procedure that is commonly available.

the way it goes is usually to create a SSRS subscription (using report manager at http://yourserver/reports) where you set destination email and parameters. afterwards you trigger the subscription with the AddEvent procedure in the ReportServer db.

It gets a bit complicated when there are too many recipients to manage manually, and if you need to change the parameters often.

If you have sql server enterprise edition, you can setup and use data driven subscriptions. You will need a table that contains emails and parameter mappings.

If you don't have enterprise edition, then it's a bit complicated. I would suggest that you have a look at https://busyreports.codeplex.com/ or similar solutions.

Comment: i ended up programming my own solution in vb.net win-forms that loops through all records in my documents table and once it send marks a flag field as a bodge job but would have preferred if everything was handled without a secondary application. i will take a look at the addevent procedure and see if there is any documentation on it.